# Rails server console with HTTP auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, authentication

I have a application in a VPS where I only have a IP and no domain address.

The client request that I put http auth for avoid external access. But he doesn't want put http auth in code, the client wants as webserver.

I am using nginx and unicorn, but for testing I need fire up the application with:

```
rails s
```

Then application run then in  and external access is still allowed.

I was wondering if there are a way to fire up the rails server console with http auth, something like:

```
rails s auth=http user=bla pass=bla
```

Comment: No there isn't, you should use a reverse proxy or a middleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could insert [something like this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html) in you `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  http_basic_authenticate_with \
    realm:    'You have no power here',
    name:     ENV['APP_AUTH_USER'],
    password: ENV['APP_AUTH_PASS']

  #…
end
```

and fire up your application like so:

```
$ APP_AUTH_USER=foo APP_AUTH_PASS=bar rails s
```

But, as [mdesantis](/users/584552/mdesantis) mentioned, you propably should setup a proper reverse proxy (Nginx, Apache+Passenger, Passenger Standalone) and make use of their authentication capabilities, so that an unauthenticated request won't hit your Rails stack at all.